# PHP + MySQL query -> What's wrong with this SQL (short)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have finally graduated from MS Access to MySQL. Unfortunately, I can't even get a query right. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? I keep getting the 'invalid query' message that I specified in the php.

```
<?php
@ $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'newdatabase');
if (!$db) {
    die ('Failed to connect to the database.');
}


$query = "SELECT first FROM demographics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('invalid query');
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['first'];
}

?>
```

Also, the book I am reading tells me to use:

```
new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'newdatabase')
```

to connect as opposed to the

```
mysql_connect
```

I used in the above code. I haven't been able to connect to the db with **new mysqli**. Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: Please use code blocks rather than quote blocks for your code, as code blocks enable syntax coloring.

Comment: PHP has 3 different ways to access mysql. the mysqli class/functions, mysql functions, and the PDO class. PDO is typically the recommended option.

Comment: Also note that for new code you want to use the MySQLI extension, not the MySQL extension. The MySQL extension is maintained only for compatibility with (ancient) MySQL 3.x databases. MySQL 4.x introduced the MySQLI API (And even 4.x is really old nowadays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth parameter to [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php) is not the database name.  It is a boolean specifying whether or not to establish an additional new connection or use an existing one.  Most often, it is omitted. Use [`mysql_select_db()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-select-db.php) to choose the database.  Since you have not selected a database in your code, your query is likely failing.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (!$db) echo mysql_error();
else mysql_select_db("database");
```

Note I have removed the `@` from the `mysql_connect()` call.  `@` suppresses errors, and was probably preventing you from seeing what was going wrong with your connection.

When testing the success or failure of a query, don't `die()`. Instead echo out `mysql_error()` while developing your application.  In production, you can replace the `echo` by writing to `error_log()` instead.

```
if (!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

As for using MySQLi instead of the basic `mysql_*` functions, MySQLi can be used in an object oriented fashion and also offers prepared statements, which can be both more efficient to use and more secure.  As mentioned in comments above, [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) is often recommended as the most flexible API for interacting with an RDBMS from PHP.

Comment: @Jerry Happy to help.  Good luck as you proceed. Be sure to read up on SQL injection, and the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It's different than working with Access.

Comment: **Clarification:** using @ suppresses error _messages_, not the errors themselves! Don't use @ on a function call unless you thoroughly understand what kind of messages you're suppressing and why they were showing up. Too many people think that using @ actually gets rid of errors!